# How can a string accept an integer?

Tags: java

Can a variable String accept integer value as well. Or can we concat integer with a string ?

Example:

```
public class TestString1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "420";
        str += 42;
        System.out.print(str);
    }
}
```

I was expecting compilation error over here because String was getting concatenated with an integer.

Answer (score 2):

JLS documentation on String concatination operator(`+`)-

[15.18.1 String Concatenation Operator +](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1)

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string
>   conversion is performed on the other operand to produce a string at
>   run time. The result is a reference to a String object (newly created,
>   unless the expression is a compile-time constant expression
>   (§15.28))that is the concatenation of the two operand strings. The
>   characters of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the
>   right-hand operand in the newly created string. If an operand of type
>   String is null, then the string "null" is used instead of that operand

That is why String + int does not produce any error. And it prints `42042`

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers have explained what's actually being executed here.

Your code will be converted to something like:

```
String str = "420";

// str += 42;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
sb.append(42);  // which internally does something similar to String.valueOf()
str = sb.toString();

System.out.print(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `int` to a `String` appends the int to the string, thus converting the int into a string.

Comment: For comparison, consider `System.out.print("The value was "+42)`. Adding to a string means appending to it, and it implies converting the second argument to string if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is given in double quotes is String and `+` is for concatenating string with an any value(int value).
So the integer value will be appended to the string.
Here

```
String str = "420";
     str += 42; // 42 will be appended to 420 and result will be 42042
```

Answer (score 0):

x=20 y=10

I am showing the Order of precedence below from Higher to Low:

B  - Bracket 
O  - Power
DM - Division and Multiplication
AS - Addition and Substraction

This works from Left to Right if the Operators are of Same precedence

Now

System.out.println("printing: " + x + y);

"printing: " : Is a String"

"+" : Is the only overloaded operator in Java which will concatenate Number to String. As we have 2 "+" operator here, and x+y falls after the "printing:" + as already taken place, Its considering x and y as Strings too.

So the output is 2010.

System.out.println("printing: " + x * y);

Here the

"*": Has higher precedence than +

So its x*y first then printing: +

So the output is 200

Do it like this if you want 200 as output in first case:

System.out.println("printing: "+ (x+y));

The Order of precedence of Bracket is higher to Addition.